# TypeError: props.theTodos.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error when compiling : "TypeError: props.theTodos.map is not a function". ive been bashing my head at this for a while and don't have a correct solution as im using hooks instead of class components

It breaks because of "handleChange" but I cant figure out why

App.js...

```
const[todos, setTodos] = useState(todosList);
    const markComplete = (id) => {
     setTodos({ todos: todos.map(todo => {
       if(todo.id === id) {
       todo.status = !todo.status
    }
       return todo;
     }) });
    }
       const handleChange = (id) => {
         markComplete(id);
       }

      return (
        <div className = "App">
         App
         <Todos theTodos = {todos} addTodo = {addTodo} handleChange = {handleChange}/>

        </div>
      );

        const todosList = [
      {
        title: "Dinner",
        id: 1,
        status: false
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        id: 2,
        status: false,
      },
      {
        title: 'Project',
        id: 3,
        status: false
      }
    ]
    Todos.js

    const Todos = (props) => {
      return (
        props.theTodos.map((todo) => (<TodoItem  key = {todo.id} todo = {todo}  handleChange = {props.handleChange}/>))
      );
    }

    TodoItem.js

    <input type="checkbox"  onChange = {props.handleChange(props.todo.id)}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set `todos` as an object, not an array.

```
const markComplete = (id) => {
 // setting todos as an object
 setTodos({ todos: todos.map(todo => {
   if(todo.id === id) {
   todo.status = !todo.status
}
   return todo;
 }) });
}
```

You should change it to

```
const markComplete = (id) => {
 // setting todos as an array
 setTodos(todos.map(todo => {
   if(todo.id === id) {
   todo.status = !todo.status
}
   return todo;
 }) );
}
```

If you `console.log`  `props.theTodos`, probably it will be an object with the key `todo` wich is the array of `todos`.

Don't forget that the initial value of the `useState` should be an array too.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
```

## Knowing the error

Just to be clear on what the error means, `.map` is a function for arrays only. If you get `foo.map is not a function` it means that `foo` isn't an array.

Comment: Great answer, got an error for an infinite loop after because of this line I suspect though ... onChange = {props.handleChange(props.todo.id)} .( Maximum update depth exceeded)

Comment: fixed it with () => props.handleChange(props.todo.id)